# How does success chance change when a certain die result counts as multiple partial successes?

Tags: statistics, dice, anydice

Dice mechanism: count wins (> 4) of [Mod]d6 ([AnyDice](https://anydice.com/program/31ffd)).

- Mod ranges from 1 to 10.
- Difficulty ranges from 1-10, 1 being trivial, 3 being moderate, 5 being difficult, and 6-10 being ever increasingly unlikely at all levels of mod.
- Game provides mechanisms for characters to "push themselves" to gain extra dice when their Mod < Difficulty (otherwise they would auto-fail), so a roll can always be attempted at the minimum possible dice pool size.

When counting wins, any die with a result of 6 counts as two wins. How does this alter the probability of success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a version](https://anydice.com/program/31fff) of that Anydice program that counts 6 as two successes:

You can now get up to 20 successes in theory when you have 10d6. That means that the probablity shifts to larger numbers of successes. It looks like this:

[image]

compared to when you do not double on a 6:

[image]

For example, for 4d6, you have lower chances for 1 or 2 successes, but higher chances for 3 or 4 successes, and gain chances to even get to 5 to 8 successes.

For your difficulty classes this means the following success rates (rounded):

| Class | 2d6 | 4d6 | 6d6 | 8d6 | 10d6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trivial (1) | 56% | 80% | 91% | 96% | 98% |
| Moderate (3) | 8% | 33% | 57% | 74% | 85% |
| Difficult (5) | 0% | 6% | 20% | 38% | 56% |
| Unlikely (e.g 7) | 0% | 0%* | 4% | 13% | 26% |

Even with the full dice pool and doubling, getting anything that needs more than 5 or 6 successes is really hard. Getting 10 successes at best has a chance of about 2% with all 10 d6.